# Unable to trigger Systick Interrupt Handler even after enabling TICKINT. Why?

Tags: stm32

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"
#define PIN_PC13     0x2000
#define ON_BOARD_LED  PIN_PC13
void LED_Init(void);

int main()
{
```

Function for Initialising on board LED of STM32F103C8T6

```
LED_Init();  
while(1)
{
        
}
return 0;
}

void LED_Init()
{
```

APB bus-2 clock enable ---> Enabled in order to use the peripheral

```
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPCEN; 

GPIOC->CRH |=GPIO_CRH_MODE13;   

GPIOC->CRH &= ~(GPIO_CRH_CNF13);

SysTick_Config(800000-1);   

//SysTick->CTRL |=0x07;
//SysTick->LOAD =8000000/10 -1;
}
```

Interrupt handler not running why?

```
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  GPIOC->ODR ^=ON_BOARD_LED;  // Toggling the on board LED
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, your SysTick configuration seems correct. Although I can't find the problem, I can give suggestions for debugging.

With a debugger, check the value of SysTick->CTRL register and be sure that the first 2 bits are 1.

With a debugger, make a few pause & continues and check the value of SysTick->VAL to be sure that SysTick is running. You should observe different values each time you pause.

Put a breakpoint into your SysTick_Handler to see if it's called. Maybe the handler is called but you have an error in your GPIO configuration or even in hardware.

This is somewhat unlikely, but if you're using a C++ compiler instead of C, see this question: [Why does my interrupt get called, but won't enter the handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57147348/why-does-my-interrupt-get-called-but-wont-enter-the-handler/57148339#57148339)

Comment: I already checked all that in the Keil IDE and yes the bits are being set when the Systick is configured but for some reason, the handler is not getting called. Also, I checked the same code in STM32CubeIDE the handler is getting called there but again when I checked in Attolic IDE in Ubuntu OS the HardFault Handler is getting called instead of the Systick handler. I am puzzled as to why the same code is acting differently in different IDE's.

Comment: Maybe compiler options are different. But first, you need to find the cause of the hard fault. Run the code line by line to find it. In Atollic, you also have a Fault Analyzer window during debugging, which shows the type of the fault.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CXX then the compiler will changes the name of your interrupt handler due to name-mangling. I spent a lot of time to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on blue pill, Keil 5.17, jlink v8 debugger, when run code in RAM 0x20000000.

add the following statement solve the problem:

SCB->VTOR = 0x20000000;

Comment: Moving VTOR to RAM - nonsense. Your whole project is broken.

Comment: My testing code always load to RAM with jlink, to save time (without flashing to nand flash), avoid wearing out the nand flash.